# NullPointerException is thrown sometimes on the non-nullable items of a list in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am currently developing a shopping list application for Android using data-binding and Kotlin, and I am getting a `NullPointerException` on an object of a type (`Item`) that cannot even be null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.example.shoppinglistapp.data.shoppinglists.models.Item.getItemPrice()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.shoppinglistapp.data.shoppinglists.models.ShoppingList.getShoppingListPrice(ShoppingList.kt:90)
    at com.example.shoppinglistapp.viewmodels.ShoppingListViewModel$onShoppingListPropertyChangedListener$1.onPropertyChanged(ShoppingListViewModel.kt:263)
    at androidx.databinding.PropertyChangeRegistry$1.onNotifyCallback(PropertyChangeRegistry.java:30)
```

In the model `ShoppingList`, which inherits from `BaseObservable`, I have a list of items:

```
@get:Bindable
val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
```

Each one of these items is of type `Item` (which is a class that also inherits from `BaseObservable`).

Since some of the properties of the shopping list depend on its items, whenever I add a new `Item` instance to the list, I subscribe to its property changes. This way, the corresponding properties of the shopping list will get updated when the item changes:

```
private val onItemPropertyChangedCallback = object: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
    override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable?, propertyId: Int) {
        when (propertyId) {
            // If the price of an item changes, we notify that the property 
            // "shoppingListPrice" of the shopping list has been updated
            BR.itemPrice -> { notifyPropertyChanged(BR.shoppingListPrice) }
        }
    }
}

...

// Thanks to the callback shown above, this property of the shopping list 
// updates automatically in the view whenever an item changes its price
val shoppingListPrice
    @Bindable(value = ["items"])
    get() = items.sumByDouble { it.itemPrice }

...

fun addItem(item: Item) {
    // We subscribe to the property changes of each new item that gets added
    item.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(onItemPropertyChangedCallback)
    items.add(item)

    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.items)
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.shoppingListPrice)
}
```

How is it possible to get a `NullPointerException` in a non-nullable type? What can I do to fix this? I cannot even reproduce this error on demand because it seems to happen at random and very rarely.

Comment: Hey i don't know what exactly you are doing but in Kotlin there are few ways to trick the null type. 1. Java API produce nulls but you mark them as non null in your kotlin 2. You set the field through reflection. So yeah, you probably have something related to these scenarios.

Comment: The type `Item` is already non-nullable by definition, so I am not sure I follow you here. Regarding reflection, I am not using any. All I can think of is that the problem might be related to concurrent access to the list, but even in that case it is still pretty odd to see instances of a non-nullable type throw a `NullPointerException`.